# Would the physical technology of inertia dampers be external or internal?

Tags: electromagnetism, shipbuilding

Mass and travel in outer space is a huge nuisance if you hope to go anywhere anytime soon with your characters (for me at least!). Rather than ignore inertia outright, I'd like to make dampening it a part of the "world." Pretending for a moment that inertia is somehow related to magnetism and a magnetic field could be the template for an inertia field or anti-acceleration field or what-have-you, would the field be created by technology on the hull of the ship 'pointed' inward, or inside the ship radiating outward?

Comment: I'd save your "additionally" for a separate question; best to ask just one thing at a time. I'd also suggest that as inertial dampening isn't a real thing, you could entirely reasonably pick something with a look and feel that you like and run with it; no-one is ever likely to be able to tell you that you did it wrong!

Comment: I removed the "additionally" portion. Still curious if that electromagnetism is inside or outside biased ;)

Answer (score 3):

It would be internal. Your ship will have engines that push the rest of the ship forward with a large amount of force. If you counteract any of that force, your entire ship won't accelerate as fast, so that's counter-productive.

Let's assume your ship is capable of pulling a constant 10g's. That means everything in your ship MUST accelerate at 10g's as well in order to remain a ship and not an expanding cloud of debris.

The normal way the engine's force translates into the acceleration that passengers feel is through the normal force from the "floor". The engines push on the floor, which pushes on the squishy people. If they are standing on the flood, the force translates through their feet to their skeleton and then onto the squishy parts.

Your skeleton can probably handle the 10g's, but fluids and squishy parts can't (at least not sustained).

So inside the ship you will have an Inertial Dampening Chamber where everything inside of it ideally feels a constant acceleration of 1g.

What your chamber will have to do is uniformly accelerate everything inside of it at the desired rate, which in this case would be 9g's.

Uniformly accelerating every single particle in a human is hard to do, but with some handwavium, your intertial-dampening-field can do this flawlessly!

**It is somehow able to apply a uniform force on all the atoms in the chamber, regardless of their charge or atomic weight.**

With everything in the chamber accelerating at 9g's, and the chamber itself accelerating at 10g's (along with the rest of the ship), your passengers will only feel a comfortable 1g.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty good. It isn't really damping inertia so much as assuring the effects aren't felt by the crew. Where does this break down? Is it just in the insanity of trying to uniformly apply the force to all the atoms?

Comment: @Zwuwdz: that and making sure you don’t break any conservation principles while doing so!

Comment: The conservation principles would mean the supporting framework of the chamber would have to be able to withstand the force from the engine, plus the opposite force of accelerating the entire contained mass within it. 

Yeah @Zwuwdz the hard part is the uniform acceleration of everything. Gravity does this.

Magnetic fields accelerate charged particles in motion, or certain types of materials.

Electric fields accelerate oppositely charged particles in opposite directions. 

Neither can accelerate the neutrons, or really even the generally neutral charge of stable atoms.

Answer (score 0):

Handwaving inertia is a common occurrence in Sci-Fi and gaming. Look around a bit and be inspired. The answer depends on what you are using for engines and what other effect you are willing to accept.

An Alcubierre drive creates a bubble of space so the bubble would be affected by any inertia, not the ship. Other theoretical drives that rely on dimension shifting or tunneling are basically not moving so no inertia and no need for a damper.

If you are using current technology like ion drives or others that we could build eg vasimir then the decision becomes what other effect are you willing to accept ...

- an outward field that deflects gravity and inertia would provide some shielding effect
- an internal field could double as artificial gravity with some fiddling rather than a uniform dampening